# How do you reference another file within a folder in HTML?

Tags: html, macos

I'm trying to figure out how to use files in HTML but for some reason this code isn't working.

```
<html>
        <title>HTML Experiments</title>
        <h1>This is a website that I made</h1>
        <ul>
            
            <li>Here is another file: <a href="InsideTheRootFile#1.html">another file</a></li>
            <li>Here is an extra file: <a href="extras#1/insideextras.html">extras</a></li>
            
        </ul>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the folders: [image: folders screenshot]

Index.html is the code that is shown above. When I run index.html everything looks fine but neither one of the links work.

Comment: The `#` symbol has a specific meaning in a link that might be confusing the browser. Try removing them. It also looks like the folder `Extras #1` has a space in its name that is missing from the URL in your code.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yep that's what the problem was. I wasn't aware that the # symbol had that effect. Thanks!